# Why is "cp35-win32" in the name of the .pyd files in the cryptography wheel package

Tags: python, cryptography, python-wheel

On my Windows machine, when I build the `cryptography` package using the instructions on [this page](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/), I end up with these .pyd files in the wheel:

- _openssl.cp35-win32.pyd
- _constant_time.cp35-win32.pyd
- _padding.cp35-win32.pyd

Based on already built wheels on PyPI, I was expecting these names for the files instead:

- _openssl.pyd
- _constant_time.pyd
- _padding.pyd

Do you know why I end up with `cp35-win32` in the file names? It is currently a problem because I have import errors inside the `cryptography` code which are related to this name difference:

```
  File "c:\long_path_prefix\.tox\lt\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "c:\long_path_prefix\.tox\lt\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 51, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi as _ffi
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Have a good day!

Answer (score 3):

These tags are based on [pep 427](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-name-convention).

They are added by default depending on the platform the wheel was built on.

In your case, you built your wheel on win32 and it is compatible with CPython3.5.

Comment: This is indeed compliant to PEP 427. However, it seems to cause problems to the import statements inside the `cryptography` code. I have updated the original question to include the stack trace of the import error.